# Can we conclude from Friis formula that high frequency mean more loss.

Tags: wireless, propagation

I am trying to understand the Friis transmission formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friis_transmission_equation From the equation in terms of directivity can we conclude that higher the frequency higher the loss and less energy will receive in the receiving antenna. I assuming this as it is proportional to square of wavelength.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, , that's what it means assuming Antenna Gains are constant by increasing effective aperture area with wavelength, and wavelength is inverse to f.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Antenna size explains the "losses". At 10X higher frequency, the quarter-wave antenna interacts with 1/10 * 1/10 smaller region of space, and the energy extracted is 1/100 of the lower frequency.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in free space that would cause higher loss at higher frequency (unless you are taking atmospheric absorption into account)...it has to do with antenna size. Its like catching rain drops with a bucket, bigger the bucket more water you would collect.